# standard for make project in c/c++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in learning C/C++. My question concerns making a project in C/C++.

When the projects consits of some header file `.h` and file `.cpp`.
In file `.h` I'm declaration a class with some methods in it. Then I want to define the methods.
**Shoud I define them  in that file header or another `.cpp` file?**

Example : I have a class in file Circle.h:

```
class Circle : {
    private:
        float r;
    public:
        Circle();
        Circle(float r);
        void Draw();
};
```

Then I want to define constructor `Circle()`, `Circle(float r)` and method `void Draw()`.
**Should I define in them in file `Circle.h` or another file that uses method of class `Circle`?** (for example: file `Circle.cpp`)

Comment: Yes, in this example you should 1) declare "class Circle" in Circle.h.  Be sure to use an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), 2) Define your implementation in a separate "Circle.cpp" source file. 3) `#include "Circle.h"` in Circle.cpp, and any client that uses "Circle".

Answer (score 1):

You should define those functions in `Circle.cpp`.

Suppose you define them in `Circle.h`, and two source files, `foo.cpp` and `bar.cpp`, include `Circle.h`. Then both object files `foo.o` and `bar.o` will contain code for those functions. Then if you attempt to link those two object files in order to build an executable, there will be a conflict between the two versions (even though they are identical).

You could define the functions in some other source file like 'Shape.cpp`, but then it would be difficult to remember where they were.

Comment: It should be mentioned I guess, that this is true unless you define the constructor within the class declaration body. Then, all this code will be inlined and there would be no problem including this header file into multiple compilation units

Comment: @Kam: Thank you, I didn't know that. But I still don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: There's no good or bad idea here, it's all about readability. If your class is small it's just easier to have everything inlined. Why clutter your code with a new compilation unit if your entire class (declaration + definition) is few lines long. Also when templates are involved, some templated definitions must go in a header file, no choice there.

Comment: @Kam: Templates are a different topic, one I don't think the OP is ready for.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to keep **[class interface](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm)** (only [declarations](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)) in your `.h` file and member implementation in, a complementary, `.cpp` file.

In your example:

**in file `Circle.h`**:

```
#ifndef _Circle_h_  
#define _Circle_h_

class Circle: {
private:
    float r;
public:
    Circle();
    Circle(float r);
    void Draw();
};

#include "Circlce.cpp"
#endif
```

**in file `Circle.cpp`**:

```
#include "Circle.h"

Circle::Circle(){
    // code
}

Circle::Circle(float r){
    // code
}

void Circle::Draw(){
    // code
}
```